# How to use reference converter within a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, valueconverter

I've created a multibinding converter (ListItemDescriptionConverter) that will combine several values into a single string as output for ListBox items.  However I don't know how to get the resource dictionary to point to the converter class in a separate .cs file.  It cannot be found when I use the following markup:

```
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="StaticResource {ListItemDescriptionConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Genres"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="Year"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
```

Is there something else I must do within the resource dictionary to access the converter class?  I cannot add the reference within `Window.Resources` as it needs to be within a resource dictionary so I can reuse the style throughout my app.

Comment: `Converter="{ListItemDescriptionConverter}"` should be `Converter="{StaticResource ListItemDescriptionConverter}"`. Of course the converter should be declared as a resource as usual, i.e. the same way you did with BasicTextStyle.

Comment: Sorry yes you're right, I must have deleted it by accident when I was messing around with the code to get it to work.  I've updated the OP accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define the converter as a resource, for example in your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins\DefaultSkinDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:ListItemDescriptionConverter x:Key="ListItemDescriptionConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can then reference it using the `StaticResource` markup extension and the `x:Key`:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ListItemDescriptionConverter}">
```

The other option is to set the `Converter` property to an instance of your converter class using element syntax:

```
<MultiBinding>
    <MultiBinding.Converter>
        <local:ListItemDescriptionConverter />
    </MultiBinding.Converter>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: OK thanks, but how would I write it if I already have <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins\DefaultSkinDictionary.xaml"/> within Application.Resources?  Sorry, I'm still very new to this.

Comment: Yes I think that's what I'm after as I get no more design time errors.  Unfortunately I am now getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll" when I run the app - however this may be unrelated to the issue raised in this thread., so I'll accept your answer.  Thanks.